# React native Dynamic Menu with slider

Tags: react-native

I want to create a summary page in react native with different items, which will be displayed through slider with card. Im using intro slider library.
I dont want to set the title and content with static text, but everything has to come from server as JSON data and map items to card.

like

```
content = [{"title": "Title 1", "item1":"value1", "item2":"value2"},{"title": "Title 2", "item1":"value1", "item2":"value2", "item3": "value3"},....]

render()
{ map(contents) =>item( implement card here and return)
}
```

What is best way to do this?

Need help with deciding json format and rendering it with map. No of items in each page, and it's name wont be be same always.

It should be a generic slider card which can display any title and items of any length and content.

[image]

Comment: my question is why the response is not coming in this format: [{"title": "Title 1", "date":"22-09-2012", "data": "xyz..."},{"title": "Title 2", "date":"22-09-2012", "data": "xyz..."},{"title": "Title 3", "date":"22-09-2012", "data": "xyz..."}]?

Comment: Can you post the response as well? So that I can better help you?

Comment: response format can be changed if required. kindly note that, in the menu left and right values are to be set from json, it need not be "date", it can be any item.

Comment: Ok, if you can change the above response format to above, I'll further tell you how to display that correctly

Comment: If you please change the json format to above mentioned format as I suggested,  following should work
    render(){
    num.map((n) => <View key ={n}>
    <Text>{n.title} </Text>
    <Text>{n.date} </Text>
    </View>
    )}

Comment: question edited as suggested. Kindly note that, it need not be "date" always. it can be any content of any length(any no. of items).

Comment: It should be a generic slider card which can display any title and items of any length and content

Comment: Pradeep, the solution which I have proposed, will have to work regardless of contents and size. It's a generic solution and even you can map images through it as well. For more details, you can see the documentation of map function as well.

Comment: In your solution <Text>{n.date} </Text> will work only if the object name "date" is present, which need not be there  in my case and there can be 'n' no. of such items to render in each page. I think some array operation is required . Hope you got my point.

Comment: Yes, I completely got your point and developed a solution for you, in the answer section. Please lemme know if that fixes your issue

Answer (score 0):

Considering your case, I have developed a solution for you. Please try the following:

```
{contents.map((item, index) => (
                    <View key={index}>{item.index}</View>
                ))}
```

If this doesn't work then try

```
{contents.map((item, index) => (
                    <View key={index}>{item[index]}</View>
                ))}
```

This solution work regardless of the property name.

Comment: Thank you for reply, This partially solves my problem but i want to apply separate style to each item and it's value(before and after ':' ), How can I extract each item title and its value? eg. {fruit:"mango"} i want to extract and apply separate style to 'fruit' as well as 'mango' in list view.

Comment: That's a separate issue, and require some custom solution which is definitely possible. Better to ask in a separate question.However if my current solution fixes your above mentioned issue, kindly accept this as a correct answer.

Comment: Kindly refer my original post, the data to be rendered as in Card given which needs the data key and value to be extracted separately to display with required style. If i create another question it will be a duplicate of the same requirement. Thank you once again for the support.